# how to add a smaller regtangle to `flm.Rectangle` ? adding the route boundary in addition to map boundary?

Tags: python-3.x, julia

I've been reading this [toturial](https://pszufe.github.io/OpenStreetMapX_Tutorial/) from OSMX and have created a set of routes on the same map. I also know what are the minimun and maximum latitude and longitude of the imaginary boundary (which I'd like to draw) is.  I saved the coordination as the following

```
# Based on some routing and comptation these are lat long of routing region within in m.bounds (far smaller)

min_lat = minimum(lats)
max_lat = maximum(lats)
min_lon = minimum(lons)
max_lon = maximum(lons)
```

Then to add another balck rectangle I did

```
flm = pyimport("folium")
matplotlib_cm = pyimport("matplotlib.cm")
matplotlib_colors = pyimport("matplotlib.colors")

cmap = matplotlib_cm.get_cmap("prism")


mf = flm.Map()
for k=1:length(links_o)
    locs = [LLA(m.nodes[n],m.bounds) for n in links_o[k]]
    flm.PolyLine(        
        [(loc.lat, loc.lon) for loc in locs ],
        color=matplotlib_colors.to_hex(cmap(3))       
    ).add_to(mf)

end


Route_BOUNDS = [(min_lon,min_lat),(max_lon,max_lat)]  # added this
MAP_BOUNDS = [(m.bounds.min_y,m.bounds.min_x),(m.bounds.max_y,m.bounds.max_x)]
flm.Rectangle(MAP_BOUNDS, color="black",weight=6).add_to(mf)
flm.Rectangle(Route_BOUNDS, color="black",weight=6).add_to(mf) # and added this
mf.fit_bounds(MAP_BOUNDS)
mf
```

But no smaller rectangle shows up. How can I add another rectangular region inside the bigger one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the size/dimensions of the "smaller" rectangle. Quite likely it is large than "bigger" or another place than the BOUNDS rectangle that that is why your are not seeing it.
You can zoom out to find out.

From your code it looks as if you mixed up the dimension
Longitude is the "x-dimension" and latitude is the "y-dimension" and in your code it is the other way around.

Comment: you're right. It was the order mismatch. Thank you!